# Detecting actual client IP which is coming via WSO2 API Gateway

Tags: wso2-api-manager

we are using WSO2 API manager 3.0.0 and WSO2 Identity Server as Key Manager (5.9.0) in our product. All the back end micro services are published in the API manager. There is a need to detect the IP of the client from which the request is coming. Currently we are getting the IP of the server where the API manager is deployed. What configuration needs to be there to get the correct IP of the requesting client?

Looking forward for reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the client IP and log it as follows.

```
 <property name="api.ut.REMOTE_ADDR"
                                expression="get-property('axis2','REMOTE_ADDR')"/>
 <log level="full">
     <property name="Actual Remote Address"
                                   expression="get-property('api.ut.REMOTE_ADDR')"/>
 </log>
```

You can send this client IP as a header or include this in the backend JWT.

Please refer - http://shammijayasinghe.blogspot.com/2016/04/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-in-wso2.html